# Cargar archivos estáticos sin necesidad de URL completa

Tags: .htaccess

Lo que deseo conseguir y que busque en GOOGLE y no lo consegui, es el cómo hacer que un archivo(imagen) que está en una ruta absoluta por ejemplo:
**/home/user/var/www/public/assets/img/image.png**

o ruta relativa a la carpeta del proyecto web:

**public/assets/img/image.png**

Al la hora de llamarla desde el html, no necesitar escribir mas que esta url:

**img/imagen.png***

necesito que el htaccess reconozca que los archivos estáticos están el la carpeta **public/assets** pero que no requiera escribir precisamente esa parte de la url, que detecte que la carpetas public/assets son BASE fija para servir archivos

Esta es lo que tengo en mi HTACCESS

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Estuve cerca de conseguirlo pero de la nada dejaba de funcionar.

Les agradeceria su consejo

Comment: Comparte como lo has intentado y el error o los errores que te arroja.

Comment: Ya actualize con el código en el HTACCESS, no me arroja ningun error, lo curioso es que aveces sirve y luego no...sobre todo cuando escribo rutas en la barra mas alla del **dominio.com/ruta/ruta**  ahi ya no detecta nada, y al regresar a la url www.dominio.com ya deja de mostrar, y solo funciona si escribo la ruta relativa

Comment: Pero te arrojaría un error al menos de 404, no? A eso me refería, en cualquier caso tómalo en cuenta para próximas consultas, o por si tienes que reabrir esta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo soluciones, hasta el momento me funciona a la perfeccion. lo consegui en otra pregunta y lo modifique a la necesidad.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
# Activamos mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on

# Definimos la ruta base, por facilidad, una única vez
SetEnvIf RUTA_BASE ^(.*)$ RUTA_BASE=/public/assets/

# Aquí nos evitamos comprobar que sea un archivo (agrego comprobación
# para detectar también directorio) en cada conjunto de reglas
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [QSA,L]

# Obtenemos todo lo que vaya tras "assets/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.+)$
# Y éstos coinciden con un archivo existente..
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{ENV:RUTA_BASE}%1 -f
# Entonces (si se cumplen todas las condiciones) redirigimos (R)
# y dejamos de evaluar el resto de reglas (L)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:RUTA_BASE}%1 [L,R]

RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```